# Terminating GAE Python Background Threads

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

What is the correct way of shutting down Google App Engine Background Threads? I have tried setting a loop variable to false and trying to join() the thread but regardless of what I try I get many calls to _/ah/stop ending finally with a "Process terminated because the backend took too long to shutdown."

It works but does not feel very stable, is there a better way of shutting them down?

some code:

```
_thread = None`
_should_run = True

def work():
    service = BqClient.getService()
    tabledata = service.tabledata()

    while (_should_run and not runtime.is_shutting_down()):
        try: 
            queue = taskqueue.Queue('stream-queue')
            tasks = queue.lease_tasks(300, 1000)
            ...do stuff and then sleep...

def startStreamThread():
    _thread = BackgroundThread(target = work)
    _thread.start()

def stopStreamThread():
    _should_run = False
    if (_thread and _thread.isAlive()):
        _thread.join(20)
```

Comment: Have you pass a timeout argument to your join() call (the default is None)? Like `if runtime.is_shutting_down(): your_thread.join(timeout=1.0)`

Comment: Yes, join(5) and the thread only sleeps 1 second per loop. But no have not tried the "runtime"

Comment: OK so I changed my background loop condition from checking a variable to `while (not runtime.is_shutting_down())` and now it works nicely. Maybe I'm not Ninja enough on Python scopes. Thanks @greg

Comment: Well it seems my happiness was premature, I still get the same thing sometimes, unclear on what it depends on

Comment: Can you provide some of your code?

Comment: I added some code to the question @greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code your thread is responsible for its own shutdown. This is a good thing because a BackgroundThread can outlive the request that spawned him.

> **If possible**, App Engine notifies the backend **30 seconds** before
>   terminating it.

If one batch of work in your loop take more than 30 sec your thread will not end properly. Maybe you can try to reduce the amount of work done in each loop and to test `runtime.is_shutting_down` before your `time.sleep`.

```
while True:
    # Do stuff that need less than 30 sec.
    do_stuff()
    # Check for shutdown or sleep.
    if runtime.is_shutting_down():
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
```

And sometime *if possible* (think hardware failure) is not possible and your backend is shutdown in a very short time.

You can never avoid abrupt shutdown. Ensure it doesn't break your application logic.